# How to add data to Chart.js on ejs using for loop?

Tags: node.js, express, chart.js, ejs

I have two datasets coming from Express called cDate, cPrice and they have data.length elements. I want to draw these datas on a chart.I tried many things but the graphic is not updating. My final sample code is here, many thanks !

```
 <% for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){  %>
    <script>
      var ctx = document.querySelector("#myChart");
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          labels: ['<%= cDate[i] %>'],
          datasets: [
            {
              data: ['<%= cPrice[i] %>'],
              label: ['<%= name[0] %>'], //Constant
              borderColor: "#3e95cd",
              fill: false
            }
          ]
        }
      });

      myChart.data.datasets.push({
        data: ['<%= cPrice[i] %>'],
        label: ['<%= name[0] %>'],
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
      })
           myChart.data.push({
        labels: ['<%= cDate[i] %>']
      })
    </script>
  <% } %>
```

Comment: You code generates `data.length` separate `<script>` elements so that the global variable `myChart` is declared several times, which is an error.

Comment: I know and I also tried to write the loop in <script>, still not working

Comment: try stringifying the data